# recv() strings of unknown encoding from sockets in c++

Tags: c++, string, sockets, unicode, recv

I'm writing some piece of client code which will connect to a server and issue it an ID - "16 byte string", and in return it will get back the same 16 byte string. I could also get unsolicited requests from this server telling me it's ID, and I'll have to send the same thing back to him as well.

When I create the string and send it,it works fine, as I am able to completely parse the reply I get and print out, and it's exactly what I sent. However, for the unsolicited request part - I am unable to read the string that is sent to me.

Here is a part of my code ..

```
 string my_send_string  = "123" ; 
 char my_send_buffer[16] ; 
 char my_reply[256] ; 
 memset(my_send_buffer,'\0', 16) ; 
 strncpy(my_send_buffer,my_send_string.c_str(),my_send_string.size()) ;
 numBytes = send(sock_fd,my_send_buffer,16,0); 
 // verified that numBytes is indeed 16 .. 
 numBytes = recv(sock_fd, my_reply, 16, 0) ; 
 // verified that numBytes recvd is indeed 16 .. 
 printf("Original Send Reply: %s\n",my_reply ); // This prints 123, as I expect. 
 memset(my_reply,'\0', 16) ; 
 numBytes = recv(sock_fd, my_reply, 16, 0) ; 
 // verified that numBytes is 16. 
 printf("Unsolicited Request:%s\n",my_reply ); // This prints ?a?p??˝س?8?

 ....
```

I think I'm encoding the received string incorrectly here - any tips on how I can fix this ? In the example above, I tried to just send it once, but if i send the string 10 times with different string ID's, I always get back the ID I send, so it's not just a one time thing.

Comment: This shows the client side of the connection. What function actually sends to this side of the connection? I would check the sent data.

Comment: it's for an assignment - I've asked the TA maintaing the server side code to clarify what encoding he's using to send back.

Comment: If the unsolicited message doesn't contain any `'\0'` in the first 16 bytes, you'll have an unterminated string in your receive buffer and `printf`ing it with `%s` will be a bad idea. Try looping over the 16 bytes and printing them individually as `%02x`. Also you could use a network diagnostic tool like wireshark to get a second opinion on what was sent to you. And if your platform has any `strace`-like tool use that to peek at the `send`s and `recv`s.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: Even worse, he's writing that `\0` past the end of the array in line 5, assuming that `my_send_string` is really 16 bytes long as presumed (not the case in the code).

Comment: @TimHortons: Apart from writing past the end of arrays and nul termination issues (why not declare `char my_send_buffer[17] = {};` to be on the safe side?), and copying the string being pretty usueless, I don't see anything wrong, and it appears to work, too. You do get back your "123", and the unsolicited request, you get _something else_. Presumably, the server's ID is really some garbled binary number, why not? It isn't required to have an ID that only consists of decimal digits, is it? So do as Wumpus Q. Wumbley suggested, and print the (binary) ID byte-by-bytes using `%02x`.